# A shorter way of Enablling/Disabling a text box from RadioButton selections

Tags: c#

Three radio buttons and a text box, grouped in one group box... Just when I select one of those radio button the text box gets enabled, for the other two radio buttons it should be disabled. Here is the code that comes to mind at first, but it looks ugly to me becuase I have copy pasted the same AllowMissingData() method to Change evnt of each radio button. I was wondering if there is a better way of writing it:

```
private void RequiredRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        AllowMissingData();
}

private void AllowBlankRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        AllowMissingData();
}

private void SuppressRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        AllowMissingData();
}

private void AllowMissingData()
{
    if (AllowBlankRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        MissingDataValueTextBox.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MissingDataValueTextBox.Text = System.String.Empty;
        MissingDataValueTextBox.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you realize that multiple RadioButtons can all point to the same event handler?

*(simply use the Visual Studio Properties Editor in the designer to assign the same handler. Alternatively, you could apply  `+= AnyRadioButton_CheckedChanged` to each of the RadioButtons' `CheckedChanged` events.)*

```
private void AnyRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (allowBlankRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        missingDataValueTextBox.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        missingDataValueTextBox.Enabled = false;
        missingDataValueTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I actually find the if-else very readable, so I resisted the urge to incorporate Jeff's concise answer. In my opinion, the more elaborate version is clearer about what it does.

I renamed all your controls to follow the `camelCase` naming convention (because `PascalCase` should be reserved for type names, etc).

Answer (score 3):

This cleans it up a little.  Removes the if statement at least:

```
private void AllowMissingData()
{
    MissingDataValueTextBox.Enabled = AllowBlankRadioButton.Checked;
    MissingDataValueTextBox.Text = AllowBlankRadioButton.Checked ? MissingDataValueTextBox.Text : System.String.Empty;
}
```